# Text are not align to each other in while loop in fpdf Using PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi I am trying to make a table data with the help of cell using FPDF PHP but text are not align with each other

Code -

```
    while ($resultArray = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult)) {    

//Date
  $pdf->setXY(17, 35+($i * 6.1));
            $pdf->SetFillColor(238, 236, 225);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
            $pdf->Cell(171, 6, formatPubDate($pubdate), 0, 0, 'L', True);

//Headline

$pdf->setXY(41, 36 + ($i * 4.4));
            //  $pdf->SetFillColor(238, 236, 225);
             $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
             $pdf->Cell(1, 14, (htmlspecialchars(iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $article))), 0, 0, 'L', True);
}
```

Here is my output [image]

Comment: FWIW you only need to set the font and fill color once (before your while loop). Where did you come up with 6.1 and 4.4 for adjusting the Y positioning?

Comment: i just test it by placing random values and put 4.4 and 6.1 .